# jQuery datepicker set date correctly in table

Tags: jquery, datepicker, insert, jquery-ui-datepicker

I'm using this jquery datepicker in a UI Page within ServiceNow: https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/

Currently, when a user selects a date (i.e 5/25/2017), 5/25/2017 gets correctly displayed in the input field in the correct format 'mm/dd/yyyy'.  However, when the UI Page is submitted, the recorded date in the underlying data table is always today's date (1/6/2017).

When I change the date format to be yy-mm-dd, the correct date gets recorded in the underlying table:

```
$j_custom( "[name='datepicker']" ).datepicker({dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'});
```

Is there a way to have the UI Page display the correct date in the correct format in the input and have it recorded correctly onSubmit?

Comment: what is your input field value you have set?

Comment: the input field value is left blank: <input type="text" name="datepicker" id="fromRow1" />

Comment: than it should work perfectly, I think while submitting form you might have changed that value

Comment: Can you create fiddle or snippet?

Comment: oh so let me clarify, if the user selects 5/25/2017, it shows up as 5/25/207 correctly in the input field.  However when they press submit, what gets recorded in the underlying table is always the current date (1/6/2017).

Comment: The problem is in the server code, it's not properly converting the date to the format that the database wants.

Comment: If it's MySQL on the server, it expects dates to be in the format `YYYY-MM-DD`.

Comment: Hi Barmar, I'm using ServiceNow, but yes it expects the date to be YYYY-MM-DD.  Is there any way to change it to mm/dd/yyyy?

Comment: Dave, in its current state your question is not very clear. I understand what your problem is, but it took way too much time to determine it which is going to cause this question to be closed. Considering editing the question so it clearly displays what the problem is and what you're expecting to happen.